# Inverse image of a variable under composite mapping

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$. ($.^{-1}$ denotes inverse image).
Is the set $f^{-1}(y)$ equal to the set $(g\circ f)^{-1}(g(y))$ for all $y$ ? 
by $y$ I mean the singleton set containing only $y$.

Comment: First, do inverses exist? It's possible for $g\circ f$ to have an inverse, but for neither $f$ nor $g$ to have one. It is also possible for $f$ to have an inverse, but for $g\circ f$ to **not** have an inverse. But assuming that all expressions make sense, well, $f^{-1}(y)$ is the unique $x\in X$ such hat $f(x) = y$. What happens if you apply $f$ to $(g\circ f)^{-1}(g(y))$? Do you get $y$?

Comment: Since f$^{-1}$(y) is a set, do you mean f$^{-1}$({y}) for an element y in Y or is y a subset of Y?

Comment: What happens if $g$ is constant, but $f$ is not?